# Neo4j streaming import memory error

Tags: java, database, memory, graph, neo4j

Im trying to do a streaming import into neo4j and I run into an out of memory error (and a subsequent crash) with the following trace:

> 2016-06-05 03:51:35.218+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Log Rotation [5]:  Starting log pruning.
>   2016-06-05 03:51:35.218+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Log Rotation [5]:  Log pruning complete.
>   2016-06-05 03:53:58.140+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.a.i.s.OnlineIndexSamplingJob] Sampled index :Node(NodeId) with 415290 unique values in sample of avg size 415290 taken from index containing 415290 entries
>   2016-06-05 03:56:37.803+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [1573526]:  Starting check pointing...
>   2016-06-05 03:56:37.811+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [1573526]:  Starting store flush...
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.019+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.s.c.CountsTracker] About to rotate counts store at transaction 1573543 to [/mnt/graph/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a], from [/mnt/graph/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b].
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.020+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.s.c.CountsTracker] Successfully rotated counts store at transaction 1573543 to [/mnt/graph/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a], from [/mnt/graph/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b].
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.982+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [1573526]:  Store flush completed
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.982+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [1573526]:  Starting appending check point entry into the tx log...
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.987+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [1573526]:  Appending check point entry into the tx log completed
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.987+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [1573526]:  Check pointing completed
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.987+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Log Rotation [5]:  Starting log pruning.
>   2016-06-05 03:56:38.993+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] Log Rotation [5]:  Log pruning complete.
>   2016-06-05 03:59:50.436+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 1123ms.

Im unable to get to the root the cause of this memory error. Can someone help me out?

EDIT: 
Here is what I've done:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("__", "__"))
session = driver.session()

with open("__.txt", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        count = count + 1
        tx = session.begin_transaction()
        statement = "MERGE (a:Node {NodeId:" + row[0].strip() + " })"
        statement += " MERGE (b:Node {NodeId:" + row[1].strip() + " })"
        statement += " MERGE (a)-[:Connection]-(b)"
        tx.run(statement)
        tx.commit()

session.close()
```

Comment: Can you put what you have done up to now?

Comment: the log snippet you've provided does not show an error at all. On a side note: you should use parameters in your Cypher instead of string concatenation.

Comment: I re-ran the code and I dont see any error trace at all, just a segmentation fault.

Comment: I can't see a error at all. do you get the crash/segfault on the client or server?

Comment: I get the crash on the server

Answer (score 0):

1. use parameters not string substitution
2. are you sure you have an index or constraint for `:Node(NodeId)``
3. you should either wrap multiple statements (lets say 1000 to 50k) in one transaction
4. or not need to use transaction at all

Comment: The idea was to simulate a streaming import. I did create an index. I really just want to know why/where so much memory is used in such a scenario.